# Image map is not working on Chrome for iOS

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, imagemap, mobile-browser

I created a non-responsive web page for mobile. It contains sliced images and image maps for their links. It's embedded in a cms that is uses bootstrap and javascript for other features on the site.

The links work fine on Safari for iOS and even on the Android phone's browser, but it doesn't work on the Chrome app for iOS. When I tap on the images, nothing happens. It's as if there were no links. Not sure why Chrome isn't picking up on the image maps. Might there be a bug in the Chrome app that rejects image maps?

```
<div class="imgContainer">
   <img class="posBANNER1" src="http://imagepath?$jpeg$&amp;wid=640" alt="Blah" usemap="#example">
   <map id="example" name="example" class="map">
      <area href="#" alt="Blah" rel="iframe" coords="134,713,501,743" class="fancybox-map" shape="rect">
      <area href="#" alt="Blah" rel="" coords="0,18,320,699" class="" shape="rect">
      <area href="#" alt="Blah" rel="" coords="321,18,638,699" class="" shape="rect">
   </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. My company was using a plug-in that resizes image maps depending on the screen size. Turns out the plug-in was out of date and wasn't getting initialized in Chrome the same as it did in other browsers. I downloaded another plug-in that worked with all browsers instead. I used [ImageMapResizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer).